# How to upload image on hyperledger composer playground?

Tags: javascript, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

I am trying to build a Block chain application for distributed image sharing and copyright protection. I am using image as an asset.

So now I want to upload an image on Hyper ledger Composer playground. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your file data into the IPFS. IPFS is a protocol and network designed to create a content-addressable, peer-to-peer method of storing and sharing hypermedia in a distributed file system.

For IPFS I recommend you to follow the [link](https://ipfs.io/)

In your application, In js file where you need to store Image. There you have to just write `ipfs` connectivity code. When you run the application at that time just make sure `ipfs daemon` started.

IPFS will give you a Hash link after successfully upload a file. You can store that hash into an asset or participate of hyperledger composer.

> for example

```
function toIPFS(file) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
        const ipfs = window.IpfsApi('ipfs', 5001,{protocol : "https"}) // Connect to IPFS
        const buf = buffer.Buffer(reader.result) // Convert data into buffer
        ipfs.files.add(buf, (err, result) => { // Upload buffer to IPFS
            if(err) {
              return
            }
             let url = `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/${result[0].hash}`
              resolve('resolved url');
          })
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file); // Read Provided File
   });
  }
```

I hope it will help you. :)